# XMLHttpRequest multiple Get Requests to read in multiple XML Files

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I want to read in multiple xml files and display them in an HTML Table. Therefore I have written following Code:

```
var request1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
request1.open("GET", path_xml_1, true);
request1.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("req1 joined!");
        /*Read first xml here and display table!!!*/
        console.log("req1 done!");
}
request1.send();
console.log("req1 send!");
var request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
request2.open("GET", path_xml_2, true);
request2.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("req2 joined!");
        /*Read second xml here and display table!!!*/
        console.log("req2 done!");
}
request2.send();
console.log("req2 send!");
```

The following has been written to console.log:

```
req1 send!
req2 send!
req2 joined!
req2 done!
```

I don't know whats happening with request1. I do just want to execute all the code inside request1.onload() and afterwards request2.onload(). Any Ideas what has to be changed?

Comment: "I don't know whats happening with request1" — Presumably there was an error of some kind. Look in the Network tab. Look at the response. Check it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the hint. I have looked inside the Network tab and found out there is just a get request for request2 send no get request for request1. Unfortunately this does not help. Any Idea?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/nokebuzici/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce that problem. I can imagine different code which would get the result you give. Have you provided a real [mcve]?

Comment: Okay you are right it is working this way. It looks like the problem is in the code. I have to reproduce the code.

Comment: What can you see in the web server logs?

Comment: I have found out the error ... one get request can't be send because i have split the string and put it together later and instead of using "/" between the folders there have been "," filled in ... thats why the path can't be found and the request can't be send